# ScopeBar in SearchBar

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to change backGroundColor of ScopeBarButton of ScopeBar in SearchBar.
How do I change it like a below.

[red][orange][yellow][green][blue][purple]

tell me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw the gradient first, get the image, and then use what ABros said to set the backgroundImage:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scopeBar.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor purpleColor].CGColor, nil];
CGFloat locations[6] = {0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0};
CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, locations);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointZero, CGPointMake(scopeBar.size.width, 0), nil);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[searchBar setScopeBarBackgroundImage:image];
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, great! But I'm sorry... I want to change "UIScopeBarButton". Then I wrote [searchBar setScopeBarButtonBackgroundImage:image forState:normal]; But it doesn't work well.
... I want to vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the color of the entire searchBar and not the scopeButton only. however you do have an option to set a background**Image** for your scope bar:

```
[searchBar setScopeBarBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"]];
```